# Why does AWS CodeDeploy initiate 3 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to deploy sources into EC2 instance.

now I'm touching with CodeDeploy, setting deploying environment.

but when I'm watching EC2 Dashboard, they're making 3 instances in there.

I can't figure out why CodeDeploy initiate 3 instances.

As I see, it's said 'deploy group' or whatnot, but why do they have that kind of making rule? why is it neccessary?

I'm going to deploy my built sources into me-made instance rather than initiating any new instances.

please enlighten me.

Comment: Did you setup Code deploy with Auto-scaling?

Comment: yes, I guess that Auto-scaling made 3 instances, I want to know what meaning of that

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your EC2 Auto Scaling Groups for those instance has a desired instance of 3. If you need only an instance, set the desired instance to 1. This does mean that when you are deploying, whatever service you are running on that one instance will be down.

Deployment Group is used to tell CodeDeploy the collection of instances to deploy your application to, instead of having to specify individual instances